# SQL integer range variable defined + PHP

Tags: php, sql, range

Is it possible to define a range of integers in SQL ? Something like this:

```
course_id |         course_name         |             description              | range/number
-----------+-----------------------------+--------------------------------------+----------------
         1 | PostgreSQL for Develop      | desc1                                | 5
         2 | PostgreSQL Admininstration  | desc2                                |20
         3 | Mastering PostgreSQL        | desc3                                |(12,18)
```

So I want the column *range/number* to be user either as an integer number or a range integers. I later want to use PHP to compare a variable ( containing an integer ), if it is different/not part from that number/range of numbers. Is this possible and how could I do this ? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to use the value in SQL, then you can just store it as a string.  It is a string, not a range.

If you want it as a range in the database, then use two columns, a lower bound and an upper bound.  I would make the bounds inclusive, so the single value `20` would be represented as `20` rather than `19`/`21`.

Some databases (notably Postgres) do support a range data type, but that is specific to those databases.

Comment: I can't use strings since I need the integer range in php, I will try later what you said and let you know.